# how to make target link one lib name when building but use another name when running in cmake?

Tags: c, cmake

I have the following build statements:

```cmake
add_executable(foo a.c)

target_link_libraries(foo crypto)
```

which makes `foo` successfully generated, because `libcrypto.so` exists in lib path.

But when `foo` is running, I want it to be dynamically-linked to `libcrypto2.so` which exists in another lib path. `libcrypto.so` and `libcrypto2.so` just differs in name (please note `libcrypto.so`'s SONAME is `libcrypto.so` and `libcrypt2.so`'s SONAME is `libcrypt2.so`).

How to achieve this in CMake? I try IMPORTED target, alias, but got no results.

Comment: Why don't build your executable initially linked with the proper library (`libcrypto2.so` in your case)? This is the most easy and clear approach. The fact that different libraries have different SONAME usually mean that given libraries are **binary incompatible**: Building against one of them and running using the other would crash the executable (or would give other undesirable effects). Note, that it is a linker (`ld`) which puts SONAME of a library into the executable. CMake cannot change that behavior.

Comment: @Tsyvarev In my situation, `libcrypto2.so` is managed by application. Application cannot use `libcrypto.so` for some reason. But I have `libcrypto.so`, don't have `libcrypto2.so`, so I can only link with libcrypto.so to generate foo. After that , I deliver it to application. They hope to run it with `libcrypto2.so` linked.

Comment: If I make foo link with `libcrypto2.so` at build time, and rename `libcrypto.so` to `libcrypto2.so` and use patchelf to change its SONAME to `libcrypto2.so`, it can work. But I want cmake solution first.

Comment: The way with renaming `libcrypto.so` to `libcrypto2.so`, changing its SONAME and linking with it looks reasonable. Actually, it is sufficient to change the library's SONAME without renaming the library file: exactly SONAME determines which file will be searched at runtime. Changing SONAME is not for what CMake has a ready-to-use helper, but you could encode running of appropriate tool in `add_custom_command` or `add_custom_target`.

Answer (score 0):

`Build` and `Runtime` are two different things.

CMake only comes into the picture at build time, not runtime. Since you are using dynamic linking, symbols will be resolved at runtime and need to be handled accordingly.

At runtime, you can point the linker to the required libs by updating `/etc/ld.so.conf` or create a new file(.conf) inside `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. To my knowledge, there is nothing you can do about dynamic linking at build time.